# R: Issue overlaying polygon in ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to plot the shapes of landmasses atop a heat map made in ggmap, and for the most part, coastlines plot well, but the continents come out as odd shapes with random lines between places.

```
Gib <- as.numeric(geocode("Gibraltar"))
overlay <- stat_density2d(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), bins = 16, geom = "polygon", data = EATL_pts)
EATL_map <-  get_map(location = Gib, zoom = 3, maptype= "satellite") 
EATL_map <- ggmap(EATL_map)
```

Here's the code for the actual plot. Each of these parts works except for the geom_polygon function.

```
EATL_map + overlay + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red", trans = "sqrt") + 
geom_polygon(data = map_data("world"), aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill = "white", color = "white")
```

Here's the output.

[image]

Any idea why the function isn't working properly? When I use the borders function in ggplot2 it gives the exact same output.

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: While I couldn't figure out a solution, this site may help: [Making Maps With R](http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html).  It explains that if the map is plotted on a smaller window, the subsetting of the dataset causes lines to connect incorrect portions of the polygon border.  I tried implementing the solution (using coord_fixed() as well as coord_map) with your data and could not get it to work.  hopefully you have better luck!

Comment: Also, if you are just looking for a bathymetric map with white land, you might look into the [marmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/marmap/vignettes/marmap.pdf) package.

Comment: @Cotton.Rockwood Thanks! I hadn't thought about the problem being that the window is too small for the plot. I was going to make four different plots for my data which spans most northern temperate coasts, but one global plot works just fine, and completely solves the issue! Thanks again!

Comment: A little closer but still has issues. The two maps do not align: EATL_map <-  get_map(location = Gib, zoom = 3, maptype= "satellite")
x.min <- attr(EATL_map, "bb")$ll.lon
x.max <- attr(EATL_map, "bb")$ur.lon
y.min <- attr(EATL_map, "bb")$ll.lat
y.max <- attr(EATL_map, "bb")$ur.lat
land <- map_data("world")
ggmap(EATL_map, base_layer=ggplot(aes(x=long,y=lat), data=land), extent = "normal", maprange=FALSE) + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = land, colour = NA, fill = "white", alpha = .5) + coord_map(projection="mercator", xlim=c(x.min, x.max), ylim=c(y.min, y.max))